# how to access key by number which is a different name in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

I've array like this

```
CONST unit=2;
var data1=[{a:aa, b:bb, c:cc},{a:dd, b:ee, c:ff}];

var data2=[{{d:aa, e:bb, f:cc}}, {a:ee, b:ff, c:gg}]
```

I want to reduce this array to this using unit value which is the number to access that position value from array

```
var data1=["bb", "ee"];
var data1=["bb", "ff"];
```

I have tried this:

```
var result = data1. map((d) => d[unit]);
```

Comment: The first line of code is a syntax error. JavaScript is case sensitive. The line starting `var data2` is a syntax error as well. At the end, you have two `data1`s. Please take the time to ensure your question is complete and doesn't have basic syntax errors (unless the question is about syntax errors, but this one isn't).

Comment: What logic is used to determine the contents of the resulting arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map to get the each object and then Object.keys to get the unit indexed value in each object.

```js
const unit = 2;
var data1 = [{
  a: "aa",
  b: "bb",
  c: "cc"
}, {
  a: "dd",
  b: "ee",
  c: "ff"
}];

var data2 = [{
  d: "aa",
  e: "bb",
  f: "cc"
}, {
  a: "ee",
  b: "ff",
  c: "gg"
}]

data1 = data1.map(v => {
  let keys = Object.keys(v);
  return v[keys[unit - 1]];
})

data2 = data2.map(v => {
  let keys = Object.keys(v);
  return v[keys[unit - 1]];
})

console.log(data1);
console.log(data2);
```